# What is the maximum length of a FCM getToken?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

`firebase.messaging.getToken()` returns a string token. Let's call this fcmToken. I want to save this fcmToken to Firebase Realtime database as the key. Put another way, the data structure would look like this `{ $uid : { fcmToken1 : timestamp1, fcmToken2 : timestamp2, fcmTokenN : timestampN } }`

**What is the maximum length of a FCM token?** It is because I want to save the FCM token as a key in Firebase Realtime database?

Comment: Also is there a better approach/data structure than my proposed one in saving multiple fcmToken from a user in Firebase Realtime database?

Comment: Why you need that? You can save many `fcmTokens` corresponding to `userId`.

Comment: Your structure should be like `{ $uid : { autoGeneratedKey :{ token :fcmToken1, timeStamp: timestamp1},  { autoGeneratedKey :{ token :fcmToken2, timeStamp: timestamp2 }`

Comment: I agree. I have feedback to Firebase team for their firebase sample to consider. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/397